# Resume an activity which is present in different task instead of creating new activity on same task

Tags: android, android-activity, back-stack, android-task, taskstackbuilder

I have an activity A in a task T1. Now, I call Activity B which gets opened on a new task T2 (because B's launch mode is "singleTask").
Now I want to go from B to A again.
In this case I do not want a new instance of activity A in task T2. Instead I want the existing instance of activity A in task T1 to be called.

Code Snippet :

From Activity A (which is present in task T1):

```
moveTaskToBack(true);
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class); // ActivityB's launch mode is "singleTask"
startActivity(intent);
```

Now, from Activity B (which is in task T2)

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityA); // ActivityA's launch mode is default one
startActivity(intent);
```

**I want the instance of Activity A from T1 to be opened instead of creating new instance of Activity A in T2.**

Any help is welcome!

Comment: Is a good practice to show the code that you have tried.

Comment: Have edited the question with sample code.

Comment: why Activity B launch mode is singleTask?

Comment: That is for a different requirement. My doubt is, how can we resume activity from different task.

Comment: What  is the root `Activity` (the one with ACTION=MAIN and CATEGORY=LAUNCHER) in Task T1?